# WSO2 ESB stuck in the middle of process

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a process which enrich product information from Icecat system and write it into multiple xml files using file writer. Total product are around 60K and it takes around 22 hours to complete the process.
However sometimes process stuck in the middle after random number of products and it does not write anything in Carbon log also source file is still there on SFTP. so it hang basically during the processing.
WSO2 is not releasing memory also.
So my queries are :

1. Can I see somewhere else for errors logs
2. Is it possible to check if process is still running or not.
3. How can I handle such scenario.

Please suggest.

Comment: could your share your mediation and tell us which version of wso2 esb you use ? When you say carbon log, you meen wso2carbon.log ? Could you have a look to wso2-esb-errors.log ?

Comment: we are using 5.0 version of WSO2 esb, mediation flow is like I have a process which enrich product  from Icecat system and write it into multiple xml files. to call Icecate we have written most of the code in custom mediator java class.Total product are around 60K and it takes around 22 hours to complete the process.Yes I meant WSO2 carbon log. I hae also checked wso2-esb-errors log but could not fine anything there. and It is also not because of out of memory error. But somehow it stuck process in between and If I put another file at same location then it also  don't pick it to process .